# Compiling builds that have Microsoft Excel in TFS

Tags: vb.net, ms-office

I am trying to compile a project in VB.net 2010 that uses Microsoft Excel dll at some points. It works all fine when I compile from my computer, but when I use TFS to queue a new build, I get the error that `Microsoft.Interop.Excel...` are not defined. I installed Microsoft Office 2010 directly on the TFS server but I still get the same error.

Are there any configuration I must perform for this to work?

**Edit:**

Typical error message you will see on a Build:

> Error BC30002: Type 'Excel.Worksheet' is not defined.
>
> Error BC30002: Type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application' is not defined.
>
> Warning BC40056: Namespace or type specified in the Imports 'Microsoft.Office.Interop' doesn't contain any public member or cannot be found. Make sure the namespace or the type is defined and contains at least one public member. Make sure the imported element name doesn't use any aliases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to include the dll's in a lib folder that is kept in TFS and reference the dll's from that location, in your project not wherever else they have been installed.

**Edit:**

Developers typically reference the Interop PIA's from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Visual Studio Tools for Office\PIA\Office15 and this folder wont exist on the server.

You need to copy these files, eg Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll to a lib or refs folder in source control and reference these DLLs from your solution instead of the ones in the PIA path.

Also note, same goes for DLLs from the Reference Assemblies folder, eg:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Windows.Forms.dll

Comment: What he said :) You have to remember that the build is going to be executing on a remote machine, so it probably won't have the office components installed.  If you add the custom DLL's into a reference folder in TFS, then add the workspace mapping in the build definition to pick it up.  Make sure the paths match on your local machine and in the workspace or it still won't know where to find it!

Comment: FYI - TFS Build does not require your DLLs to be in source control; it only requires that your references are correct on the machine where the build is occurring.

Comment: @RyanRiehle: yep, but the easiest usually best way to do that is to make it part of the source tree.  You might want to put it elsewhere if you reference the same DLL from unrelated TFS projects and want to make sure the versions stay in sync.   But generally, if it's part of the VS project, it should be in the TFS project.

Comment: I did that and it finally worked. Still I had the feeling that if Office was installed in the agent machine that the problem would be solved. Nevertheless, thank you all.

Comment: @DavidBrunelle: I don't think Office includes the interop files, those are either created by VS or part of a SDK.  If you get them from a SDK, you could install the SDK on the build server, and that would work.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case it makes a difference, you mentioned your TFS server, but that is not necessarily where your build is occurring.

The build report (likely where you saw the error in TFS) should indicate the path to where the build machine is storing the source code - by default the path is somewhere under c:\build. A good first step would be to go to the desktop of the machine where the build agent is installed (You can see a list of the build agents by right-clicking on the Builds node in Team Explorer and choosing Manage Controllers...)  Once you are on the desktop of the correct machine, copy the source folder from that path to some other place on the same machine and open the new copy solution file and build it in Visual Studio.  Troubleshoot the build as if you would on your local machine - something is missing on that build machine and these steps should help you find it more easily.

Comment: I'll check but I am pretty sure the build controller is the same server as TFS

Comment: Please note that there is a distinction between something named a Build Controller and a Build Agent;  they are very different things.  The Build Controller more or less chooses the build agent to perform the build.  A Build Agent is where the build is actually being performed.  These services frequently run on separate machines.  Since the machine hosting your Build Agent is where the build is occurring, this is where you will want to ensure that your references are correct.

Comment: That might makes sense. Then I'll do my best to make my personal machine the build agent since I know it contains everything I needed

Comment: When I try to create a new agent, I don't actually have a lot of options. I can select a controller and activate it. How can I create an agent for TFS on another machine ? Do I have to install specific stuff in my machine and run it from there???

Answer (score 0):

You should try to run the build on the **build machine** manually. First in visual studio, and then with msbuild. This should fail, but but you're likely to get a better idea of what is going on, and why it's failing. It's possible that your excel dll isn't located in the same place as it is on your own machine.

Comment: The build is perfect when I run it from my computer, but I don't know if it's possible to make the TFS build from my computer.

Comment: I meant that you should try to **manually** run the build on the **build machine**, not your workstation. Try to open Visual Studio on the build machine and compile your project.

Comment: Make senses. I'll try it ASAP

Comment: After verification, it seems that it will compile just fine when I run it from Visual Studio on the same server that is the build controller, but still won't when I run it using the Build Controller. How can I try the MSBuild compile ?

Comment: go the build explorer, open the recent failed build. click on view log, and scroll to the compilation log entry (it's likely that if you press 'Next Error' you'll get close to it). Under **Run MSBuild for Project**, you'll have the msbuild command line with its arguments. copy it, and run it from the Visual Studio command prompt. That will give you the error results you need. You may change some parameters like *Verbosity* to clarify the problems.