# Error Using OleDbConnection

Tags: c#, oledbconnection

I am trying to connect with the below string but it gives a compile error.  Weird portion is, it works fine on one machine but throws error on another machine!!!  Below is my code and my error, can someone point out what I should change:

```
database = "\\\\Mithril\\Databases\\Master.mdb";
System.Collections.Hashtable lookup = new System.Collections.Hashtable();
//This is the error line
OLEDBConnection olecon = new OLEDBConnection(
"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + database.ToString());
```

And here is the compile error I am getting:

```
Error 2 Cannot create an instance of the abstract class or 
interface 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.OLEDBConnection'
```

EDIT --------------------

I have also tried:

```
using System.Data;
System.Data.OleDb.OLEDBConnection olecon = new System.Data.OleDb.OLEDBConnection(
"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + database.ToString());
```

And this presents a different compile error:

```
Error 19 The type or namespace name 'OLEDBConnection' does not exist in the 
namespace 'System.Data.OleDb' (are you missing an assembly reference?
```

Comment: Are you sure you didn't mean to use `System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection`?

Comment: See additional code added

Comment: Yes, C# is case sensitive. `OleDbConnection` isn't the same as `OLEDBConnection`.

Comment: @JonSkeet -- That was it.  The case issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your code is referencing the[Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.OLEDBConnection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.oledbconnection%28v=office.15%29.aspx) interface, where you probably instead want the [System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbconnection.aspx) interface.

The excel interop interface will only build correctly on machines where the required assembly is available (which is probably will be if Excel is installed), while the `System.Data.OleDb` interface is part of the .Net framework and so will work on all machine where the .Net framework is installed.

If you did intend to use the excel interop interface then it would be a good idea to add the required interop assemblies to some sort of "lib" directory alongside your source and reference it from there instead.  See [Compiling builds that have Microsoft Excel in TFS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11477914/compiling-builds-that-have-microsoft-excel-in-tfs)