# TFS Build - iSeries Reference

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

I am working through setting up our first build definition through TFS 2013.  I have worked through all of the errors (mostly missing reference files) except one:

```
Type 'iDB2Command' is not defined.
```

The type is part of IBM.Data.DB2.iSeries.dll, which I have placed on the build server in the appropriate location.  I am really at a loss as to what to do in this situation.

Obviously building through Visual Studio works just fine.  The file is not registerable.  The iSeries client/SDK installs are not necessary (I do not have them on my machine, and I can build).

My best guess is that it wants the .NET 2.0 SDK (TFS is running on Windows Server 2013 and I already had to install several versions of the Windows and .NET SDKs).

How do I get my build to see this file and complete?

Comment: Have you tried logging onto the build server and opening the solution in Visual Studio and seeing if you can build?

Comment: No.  I am not allowed to install Visual Studio on the build server.  I have been installing the SDK's as needed to clear errors for missing references.  I think I finally have it, though.  I had to move the Excel interop to a common folder within the solution, and doing that for this DLL seems to have worked as well.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately this appears to have been a permissions issue.  By following advice similar to the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11477914/compiling-builds-that-have-microsoft-excel-in-tfs) (which I had to do for the Excel reference), I needed to put the IBM DLL into a Libs folder within the Team Project.

Once I did this, and updated the references in the solution, the build worked just fine.